# Mensaje de error: La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor

Tags: sql-server

Necesito de su ayuda para identificar el error en el siguiente procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server, mis conocimientos son limitados así que les pido discreción por el código que a continuación les presento.

El siguiente procedimiento almacenado debe permitir inscribir a un estudiante a una materia ya existente.
El contenido de las tablas que participan en ella es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE Alumnos(
    [IDAlumno]          [int]           NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY     IDENTITY(1,1),
    [nombre]            [varchar](200)  NOT NULL,
    [IDusu_alumno]      [int]           NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (IDusu_alumno) REFERENCES Usuarios(IDUsuario)
); 
CREATE TABLE Materias(
    [clave_Materia]     [char](4)       NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY,
    [nom_Materia]       [varchar](60)   NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (profe_Materia) REFERENCES Profesores(IDProfesor)
);

CREATE TABLE Inscritos(
    [folio_Inscritos]   [int]       NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY     IDENTITY(1,1),
    [alu_Inscrito]      [int]       NOT NULL,--Ejemplo: 2
    [materia_Inscrito]  [char](4)   NOT NULL,--Ejemplo: 2x2B

    FOREIGN KEY (materia_Inscrito) REFERENCES Materias(clave_Materia),
    FOREIGN KEY (alu_Inscrito) REFERENCES Alumnos(IDAlumno)
);
```

El procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente:

```
alter PROCEDURE spAltaAlumnoAMateria(
      @ErrorMessage   varchar(2000)
 ,@ErrorSeverity  tinyint
 ,@ErrorState     tinyint,
 --@IDUsuario varchar(50),
 @nom_usuarioONLINE varchar(50),
 @claveMateria char(4),
 @IdAlumno int

)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DECLARE @pruebaA int;
            SET @pruebaA = (SELECT IDAlumno FROM Alumnos WHERE IDAlumno = @IdAlumno);
            declare @pruebaM CHAR;
            set @pruebaM =(select clave_Materia from Materias WHERE clave_Materia=@claveMateria)

            DECLARE @IDUsuarioONLINE int;
            SET @IDUsuarioONLINE = (SELECT IDUsuario FROM Usuarios WHERE nom_Usuario = @nom_usuarioONLINE);
            Declare @PruebaInscrito char;
            set @PruebaInscrito =(SELECT materia_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE materia_Inscrito = @claveMateria)
            declare @PruebaInscrito2 int;
            set @PruebaInscrito2 = (SELECT alu_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE alu_Inscrito = @IdAlumno)


            DECLARE @AlumnoIngresado int;
            declare @MateriaInscrita char;
            --IF(@tipo_usuAlta = 0)

            BEGIN
                IF(@pruebaA is null)
                    BEGIN
                        PRINT 'El alumno ingresado no ha sido encontrado'
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        IF(@pruebaM IS NULL)
                            BEGIN
                                   PRINT 'La materia ingresada no ha sido encontrada';  
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN 
                            IF((@PruebaInscrito) is not null AND (@PruebaInscrito2) is not null)
                                BEGIN

                                    PRINT 'El alumno seleccionado ya esta inscrito a esa materia'
                                END

                            ELSE 
                                BEGIN
                                    INSERT INTO Inscritos VALUES ( @IdAlumno,@claveMateria);
                                    --SET @AlumnoIngresado = (SELECT alu_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE alu_Inscrito = @IdAlumno);

                                    --set @MateriaInscrita =(select materia_Inscrito from Inscritos where materia_Inscrito = @claveMateria)
                                    --INSERT INTO fotos VALUES (@idcreada, @foto_usuAlta);
                                    INSERT INTO Bitacora VALUES (@IDUsuarioONLINE, @nom_usuarioONLINE  + ' ha dado de alta a un alumno con clave: ' + CAST(@IdAlumno as nvarchar) + 'a la materia con clave de referente: ' + @claveMateria + '.',GETDATE());
                                    PRINT 'Inscripcion a materia '+@claveMateria +': ' + CAST(@IdAlumno as nvarchar) + ' ha sido dado de alta satisfactoriamente.';

                                END
                            END
                        END                         
                END
                ----------------
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ErrorMessage  = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    SET @ErrorState    = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    --BREAK 
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END CATCH
END 

exec spAltaAlumnoAMateria null,null,null,'roxuan', '1X2B', 1
```

El ejecutable es de un usuario que ya esta ingresado en la tabla 'Inscritos'.
Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probablemente el error esté en la siguiente línea

```
set @PruebaInscrito =(SELECT materia_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE materia_Inscrito = @claveMateria)
```

La consulta devuelve más de un resultado puesto que hay más alumnos inscritos en esta materia y debes especificar en el `WHERE` el `alu_Inscrito` para delimitar materia y alumno. De esta forma quedaría

```
set @PruebaInscrito =(SELECT materia_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE materia_Inscrito = @claveMateria AND alu_Inscrito = @IdAlumno)
```

El error persiste en la siguiente línea, pero habiendo subsanado la anterior es prescindible, así que las siguientes dos línea la puedes eliminar

```
declare @PruebaInscrito2 int;
set @PruebaInscrito2 = (SELECT alu_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE alu_Inscrito = @IdAlumno)
```

Luego, cuando haces las comprobaciones, acuérdate de eliminar la referencia a 
`@PruebaInscrito2`

```
IF(@PruebaInscrito is not null) //por IF((@PruebaInscrito) is not null AND (@PruebaInscrito2) is not null)
```

Comment: Estaba en lo correcto, muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que alguna consulta de las que asignas a una variable, devuelve varios resultados, y estas intentando asignárselos a una variable.

```
   DECLARE @IDUsuarioONLINE int;
            SET @IDUsuarioONLINE = (SELECT IDUsuario FROM Usuarios WHERE nom_Usuario = @nom_usuarioONLINE);
   Declare @PruebaInscrito char;
            set @PruebaInscrito =(SELECT materia_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE materia_Inscrito = @claveMateria)
   declare @PruebaInscrito2 int;
            set @PruebaInscrito2 = (SELECT alu_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE alu_Inscrito = @IdAlumno)
```

Cualquiera de estas asignaciones puede devolver varias filas, y le estás asignando a una variable, que solo está concebida para albergar un valor.

La tabla usuarios, no la vemos, por tanto no se puede decir que alu_inscrito sea primary key o unique.
Pero tanto alu_Inscrito como materia_inscrito, pueden tener en la tabla de inscritos varias filas. Ya que es precisamente una table de muchos a muchos, donde un alumno puede inscribirse en varias materias o a una materia, puede tener varios inscritos.

Puedes cambiar las variables escalares declaradas, por variables de tabla, que inserten varias filas. O también puedes implementar el operador TOP en las querys para ir depurando, ya que este te garantizará que solo devuelve un valor y podrás ejecutar correctamente el procedure, aunque eso no quita para que luego tengas que pensar lo que ya te he comentado.

Como Ejemplo:

```
set @PruebaInscrito =(SELECT TOP(1) materia_Inscrito FROM Inscritos WHERE materia_Inscrito = @claveMateria)
```